# длинна первичного ключа MySQL

Tags: mysql

я имею следующую таблицу:

```
+---------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type                 | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id      | smallint(5) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| version | varchar(15)          | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| num     | smallint(5) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| type    | enum('ios','and')    | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+---------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Почему длинна ключа индекса равна 48 ?
По моим расчетам длинна ключа должна быть 16 byte (version) + 1-2 байта enum?
т.е. не больше 24 байт

MySQL version  5.7.27

кодировка  CHARSET=utf8

Comment: А кодировка какая у колонки ? varchar(15) - это 15 символов. А символ в utf-8 и 6 байт может быть, правда mysql почему то считает что только 3

Comment: (15*3+1)+(1+1)=48. 15 символов **в трёхбайтовой кодировке** плюс длина для VARCHAR. Кстати, дефолтное значениt NULL для NOT NULL поля - странненько как-то...

Comment: а почему трехбайтная,  CHARSET=utf8 - двухбайтная кодировка. Попробую изменить на однобайтную

Comment: после замены на однобайтную кодировку длинна ключа стала 18 байт

Answer (score 0):

Изначально была задана таблица в кодировке UTF-8, которая использует переменное количество байт (от 1 до 4). После смены кодировки на ASCII длинна ключа стала 18 байт

```
15 + 1 -> VARCHAR(15)
1 + 1 -> enum
```

Спасибо за подсказку @Mike & @Akina